# gtk focus orders

Tags: linux, gtk

In a widget, like the gtk button, the default focus order is "focus out" first and then "focus in".
I wonder, is there a method that would show "focus in" first and then show "focus out"?
I connected the button with "focus-in-event" and "focus-out-event".
For example, two button, button A and button B.
The default focus has already put on A.When I move to B.The result is, A got focus out then B got focus in. Is there a method to let B got "focus in" first, and then A got "focus out" signal ?

Comment: What do you mean by default order? Do you mean that previously focused widget gets "focus-out" before newly focused widget gets "focus-in"? Otherwise AFAIK to get a "focus-out" your button should have got "focus-in". Try [this](http://pastebin.com/QtLC21WN) sample, you will see that the button gets "focus-in" before "focus-in". Btw what are trying to do?

Comment: For example, two buttons, button A and button B. The default focus has already put on A.When I move to B.The result is, A got "focus -out-event" then B got "focus-in-event". Is there a method to let B got "focus in" first, and then A got "focus out" signal

Comment: AFAIK that may not be possible. Because button A had focus, it has to get the "focus-out" first as it loses focus first & only then button B will get "focus-in". What exactly are you trying to achieve? Maybe there are other way to do it like you can change the widget which has the default focus.

Comment: Actually AFAIK only one widget can have focus. So in case you have focus-in first then at that instance you will more than one widget with the focus, as previously focused widget is yet to get focus-out. Thus the scheme!

Comment: Well, thank you for your answer. Now I understand the scheme. I found sometimes it looks like  a little slow with this mechanism, especial in embed system. I will try some other ways.